# Parsing InputDialog input to string in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm working on a GUI game application (TicTacToe). I'm a beginner and i don't have any good understanding with java.
So, in the application I used InputDialog to get player1 name and player2 name from user. Then parse them to string? I don't know the code for that. The code for input dialog is

```
 String input_p1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter player1 name : ");
```

The reason I want to parse it to string is so that I can use it later for showing the name of the player in labels, when the game starts.

Please help me suggest suitable and simple code for it..

Comment: already you got name in the variable input_p1

Comment: `input_1` is already type String, so there's no need to parse anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to parse here. What you have is perfect, and as simple as it gets.

When the dialog comes up and the player types their name in, when they hit OK, it'll be saved to `input_p1`. If they hit cancel, `input_p1` will be `null`.

`input_p1` will contain the player name. Just use that to show the player's name again.

Answer (score 0):

if pressed ok button user entered value will be saved in variable `input_p1. Here you don't need to parse. Because JOptionPane return it as String value.
Simply check by

```
System.out.println(input_p1);
```